# popup of are you sure you want to open it when certain scripts are ran

Tags: php, apc

im on a mac using mamp/mamp pro.

when i open apc scripts i keep getting this warning

```
“apc-6.php” is a script application downloaded from the Internet. 
Are you sure you want to open it?
```

ive downloaded and setup one of these scripts to test if apc works for me 
http://pecl.php.net/package/APC

and when i click around a message box with the above text is shown. what causes this and how can i stop it? its annoying.

thanks

Comment: Usually programs have a "Stop showing this warning" checkbox on the alert. Evidently Apple isn't smart enough to put that in...

Answer (score 0):

Check out these links:

- [Lift the leopard download quarantine](http://henrik.nyh.se/2007/10/lift-the-leopard-download-quarantine)
- [Leopard are you sure you want to open it](http://www.davinian.com/os-x-leopard-are-you-sure-you-want-to-open-it/)

Seems like there's no easy solution. But I think in snow leopard should be an option to disable the message for further events.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox triggers a download dialog any time it doesn't receive a content-type header, which happens when php segfaults.  MAMP comes with Zend Accelerator enabled by default which, when combined with APC, causes segfaults.  You can probably see this happen if you tail your apache  error log -- segfaults are recorded there.

Disable zend accelerator in your MAMP config.

Answer (score 0):

Type in Terminal:

> defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSQuarantine -bool NO

or open /User/[username]/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist in Property List Editor and uncheck 'LSQuarantine'.

Then restart the computer. There may be a way to reload the LaunchServices from the command prompt but restarting is a sure bet.

This action should come with a serious disclaimer as it bypasses an OS X security feature but in the 9 months I've run Snow Leopard and been getting those messages, I've never had one I didn't authorize.